android webview:How to copy contents in webview by user-select?
I have a webView. WebView shows html with text, images, buttons etc.
I want to make few things.
That user can  select text in webView,
and user can copy the text that user selected
I have used：
user-select: text
Only the text is selected without showing the copy panel  in some android webview

Can you share the logic you have in place? Also, please clarify what works and what doesn't and what you actually want.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
